# throw 404 when requested url/controller doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I've modified my WindsorControllerFactory to throw HttpException 404 when the requested controller doesn't exist

but I'm not sure if this is a good way of doing this, anybody knows if there can be any problems with this ?

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
        var controllerTypes =
            from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
            select t;
        foreach (var t in controllerTypes)
            container.Register(Component.For(t).LifeStyle.Transient);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        //if (controllerType == null) return null;
        if (controllerType == null) throw new HttpException(404, "page not found");
        return (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always a good place to start for this sort of thing is in the Windsor Wiki see http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-two-plugging-Windsor-in.ashx